# Kendo Gird .Update call java script function

Tags: kendo-grid

Below is my Kendo grid and i need to call a javascript/jquery function on click of update button.

Can some one please suggest solution for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQf0A.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the before edit event.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Events(e => e
            .BeforeEdit("gridBeforeEdit")
        )
    )
    <script>
    function gridBeforeEdit(e) 
    {
            if (e.model.isNew()) {
                //Handle create record   
            }
            else{
                //Handle update record
            }
    }
    </script>
```

Please refer to this [API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events) for all the available events for Kendo grid.